# I am trying to SSH into a server and it hangs at login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I am trying to SSH into a server and it hangs at login. This is the output of `ssh -v`:

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to $$$$$$ [888.888.888.888] port 22.
```

I have generated ssh-keys on the client and placed its public key (`id_rsa.pub`) in the host's `authorized_keys`.

All machines are connected with a physical cable, not wireless. I can successfully ssh from the client to another separate machine on the same network, and I can also ssh from that separate machine to the host successfully. Finally I am able to SSH from host to client. But when I try to SSH from client to host it hangs.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post: “[Troubleshooting sshd server configuration.](https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/troubleshooting-sshd-server-configuration-2/)”

Especially the part,

1. run `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -D -p 222` on the server.
2. run `ssh -v -C -A -X -p 222` on the client.

Normally the log on the server side will reveal what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (on MacOS), but did not have the option to run anything on the server side as the accepted answer suggests.
I went through many troubleshooting steps (see below), and in the end it seems like I have some DNS issue which is blocking the connection to the port, and for some reason I am not getting a `Could not resolve hostname` error. IT support confirmed that none of my login requests were coming through to the host.

Eventually what worked was to run `nslookup server.domain-name.de` to find the IP address. It returns:

```
Server:     XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Address:    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX#XX

Name:   server.domain-name.de
Address: XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
```

Using the second `Address`, I tried logging in again as follows:
`ssh user_name@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX`
which worked fine!

Other troubleshooting steps which did not work for me but might work for others:

- In System Preferences > Sharing, check that Remote Login is enabled for all users
- Use the Network Utility app (easily found through Spotlight with `CMD + Space`, `Network Utility`) enter the server domain name and scan for open ports. This told me that port 22 was indeed open.
- I went to `~/ssh/ssh_config` and added `GSSAPIAuthentication no` to the uncommented options in the lines below `Host *`.
- I restarted my MacBook, checked my firewall was off, and tried on a VPN.
- I tried `ssh localhost`, which worked. I tried to connect to a different server, but had the same problem of being stuck on connecting to port 22.
- And of course I checked that my username was spelled correctly.
- Once we figured out it was likely a DNS issue, we tried flushing the DNS cache:

  ```
  sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
  sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper
  sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
  ```

  but this didn't fix the issue for me.