# High variance of SSH connect latency

Tags: ssh, latency

I am trying to SSH to a remote server. Sometimes I connect quickly in under a second. Other times, it takes much longer - between 7 and 25 seconds.

I tried running with `ssh -v` for debugging. When it takes longer, it hangs on

```
debug1: Connecting to <hostname> [<ip_address>] port 22.
```

Any ideas what might be causing this issue? Or things I can do to debug it?

Comment: Could it simply be networking issues? What happens when you Ping the server? Or even run a Traceroute to that server? My guess is there is simply some network bottleneck for new connections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to ssh into a server and it hangs at login](https://superuser.com/questions/599253/i-am-trying-to-ssh-into-a-server-and-it-hangs-at-login)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with network debugging tools. When I run ping <hostname>, the ping is around 5 ms. When I run ssh and it's fast, the ping doesn't change. When I run ssh and it's slow, it increases to around 80-200 ms. It seems to increase in reaction to running the ssh command.

Comment: I just installed traceroute, but I'm not sure how to interpret the output.

Comment: The linked answer could definitely be on the right track -- I'll run some of those tests on Monday when I have access to the sys admins for the ssh server.

Comment: “When I run ssh and it's slow, it increases to around 80-200 ms.” Networking issues. Ping is simply a basic response to another machine on the Internet. If somehow the ping were consistent, yet SSH connection was slow, then that would be a pure SSH issue. If they both show slowdowns it would be a network issue. Traceroute output shows the network hops between you and the destination. Delayed connection would show some kind excessive response time on one hop. I would also recommend installing [MTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)) which is like traceroute and ping combined.